# sed/awk: replace N occurrence 

Tags: sed, awk

it's possible to change N (for example second occurrence) **in file** using one-line sed/awk except such method?:

```
line_num=`awk '/WHAT_TO_CHANGE/ {c++; if (c>=2) {c=NR;exit}}END {print c}' INPUT_FILE` && sed  "$line_num,$ s/WHAT_TO_CHANGE/REPLACE_TO/g" INPUT_FILE > OUTPUT_FILE
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To change the Nth occurence in a line you can use this:

```
$ echo foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar | sed 's/foo/FOO/2'
foo bar FOO bar foo bar foo bar
```

So all you have to do is to create a "one-liner" of your text, e.g. using `tr`

```
tr '\n' ';'
```

do your replacement and then convert it back to a multiline again using

```
tr ';' '\n'
```

Comment: Thanks, good trick with TR - because without that 's/foo/FOO/2' doesn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

This awk solution assumes that WHAT_TO_CHANGE occurs only once per line. The following replaces the second 'one' with 'TWO':

```
awk -v n=2 '/one/ { if (++count == n) sub(/one/, "TWO"); } 1' file.txt
```