# How to replace Nth match in a line with awk

Tags: awk, gawk

In `sed` you can replace the Nth match using `/N` ([solved so long ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6586115/1983854)):

```
$ sed 's/you/ME/1' <<< "hello you are you"  # 1 is superfluous here, though
hello ME are you
$ sed 's/you/ME/2' <<< "hello you are you"
hello you are ME
```

I am trying to accomplish the same in `awk` and the only dirty way I found is looping through the elements and keeping a counter.

Even the simpler case, where the match is a full field, gets a bit dirty:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="you" && ++c==2) $i="ME"}1' <<< "hello you are you"
hello you are ME
```

Thus, I wonder if any of the `gensub()`, `gsub()` or `sub()` functions allow you to provide such parameter to do it in a more straight-forward way. Going through the [String functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) in the GNU awk manual did not show help me to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `gensub()`. I think it's only included in [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk) version, but it accepts a regular expression to match, replacement text and the position:

```
awk '$0 = gensub(/you/, "ME", 1)' <<< "hello you are you"
```

that yields:

```
hello ME are you
```

and

```
awk '$0 = gensub(/you/, "ME", 2)' <<< "hello you are you"
```

that yields:

```
hello you are ME
```

Comment: Ooooh I tried this one but I did not remember `gensub()` doesn't replace `$0` but outputs it. That is, `awk 'gensub(/you/, "ME", 2)'` did not work to me because it was printing the original value. Nice one, many thanks!